# Airflow - how to make EmailOperator html_content dynamic?

Tags: airflow

I'm looking for a method that will allow the content of the emails sent by a given EmailOperator task to be set dynamically.  Ideally I would like to make the email contents dependent on the results of an xcom call, preferably through the html_content argument.

```
alert = EmailOperator(
    task_id=alertTaskID,
    to='please@dontreply.com',
    subject='Airflow processing report',
    html_content='raw content #2',
    dag=dag
)
```

I notice that the Airflow docs say that xcom calls can be embedded in templates.  Perhaps there is a way to formulate an xcom pull using a template on a specified task ID then pass the result in as html_content?  Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Use `PythonOperator` + `send_email` instead:

```
from airflow.operators import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.email import send_email


def email_callback(**kwargs):
    with open('/path/to.html') as f:
        content = f.read()
    send_email(
        to=[
            # emails
        ],
        subject='subject',
        html_content=content,
    )


email_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task_id',
    python_callable=email_callback,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)
```

Answer (score 12):

For those looking for an exact example of using jinja template with EmailOperator, here is one

```
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

email_task = EmailOperator(
    to='some@email.com',
    task_id='email_task',
    subject='Templated Subject: start_date {{ ds }}',
    params={'content1': 'random'},
    html_content="Templated Content: content1 - {{ params.content1 }}  task_key - {{ task_instance_key_str }} test_mode - {{ test_mode }} task_owner - {{ task.owner}} hostname - {{ ti.hostname }}",
    dag=dag)
```

You can test run the above code snippet using

```
airflow test dag_name email_task 2017-05-10
```

Comment: I cant seem to be able to use "{{ds}}" in the filename. Any ideas guys? :/

Comment: html_content = "Templated Content: date: {{ ds }} " should work

Comment: I thought it wasn't working when I was using things like `{{ ti }}` and `{{ dag }}`, but it seems that these are objects and are substituted with an empty string - not what I was expecting.

Answer (score 9):

might as well answer this myself.  Turns out it's fairly straight forward using the template+xcom route.  This code snippet works in the context of an already defined dag.  It uses the BashOperator instead of EmailOperator because it's easier to test.

```
def pushparam(param, ds, **kwargs):
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='specificKey', value=param)
    return 

loadxcom = PythonOperator(
    task_id='loadxcom',
    python_callable=pushparam,
    provide_context=True,        
    op_args=['your_message_here'],
    dag=dag)

template2 = """
    echo "{{ params.my_param }}"
    echo "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='loadxcom', key='specificKey') }}"
"""
t5 = BashOperator(
    task_id='tt2',
    bash_command=template2,
    params={'my_param': 'PARAMETER1'},
    dag=dag)
```

can be tested on commandline using something like this:

```
airflow test dag_name loadxcom 2015-12-31
airflow test dag_name tt2 2015-12-31
```

I will eventually test with EmailOperator and add something here if it doesn't work...

Comment: Did you succeed in making the EmailOperator dynamic? What approach did you use?